# I need help access admin.messaging() in Firebase

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I want visitors to be automatically subcribed to topics on my website. In my index.js file I have activated my app like this.

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./service-account.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://my-project.firebaseio.com"
});
```

and on my webpage I have done this

```
var setTopic = getTopic();
admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(currentToken, setTopic)
              .then(function(response) {
                // See the MessagingTopicManagementResponse reference documentation
                // for the contents of response.
                console.log('Successfully subscribed to topic:', response);
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Error subscribing to topic:', error);
              });
```

When the page is loaded I am getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'messaging' of undefined
at Object.next ((index):411)
at subscribe.ts:104
at subscribe.ts:233
```

I am not sure why this is happening as i have followed the installation instructions to the letter.

Comment: You cannot use `firebase-admin` in a client-side app (like a web page). It must be used in a backend server.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that. But it still doesn't seem to be working. The topic is not being created and the client app not being subscribed.